# How get response body on php guzzle?

Tags: php, guzzle

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post('http://httpbin.org/post', array());
```

How i can get body response?

getBody **not returned** response body

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($response->getBody(), true) . '</pre>';
```

```
GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream Object
(
    [stream:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Resource id #80
    [size:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 
    [seekable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
    [readable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
    [writable:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => 1
    [uri:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => php://temp
    [customMetadata:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

how print body response?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `getContents` method to pull the body of the response.

```
$response = $this->client->get("url_path", [
                'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $my_token]
            ]);
$response_body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
print_r($response_body);
```

When you pull make guzzle requests, you'll typically put it in a try catch block. Also, you'll want to then decode that response as JSON so you can use it like an object. Here's an example of how to do it. In this case, I am authenticating with a server:

```
    try {

        $response = $this->client->post($my_authentication_path, [
            'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $this->base_64_key,
                            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
                            ],
            'form_params'    => ['grant_type' => 'password',
                            'username' => 'my_user_name',
                            'password' => 'my_password']
        ]);

        $response_body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    } catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e){
        $response_object = $e->getResponse();
        //log or print the error here.
        return false;
    } //end catch

    $authentication_response = json_decode($response_body);
    print_r($authentication_response);
```